# PrepareTableForFaking cannot remove Index

Tags: t-sql, tsqlt

(Full disclosure, while I'm a fairly experienced .NET dev, t-sql is still new to me.)

I'm trying to implement tSQLt on a fairly massive DB, with 10 years of data, and I'm running into roadblock after roadblock.

First, it was SchemaBinding that was the problem, which lead me here: http://tech.4pi.si/2015/01/tsqlt-faketable-fails-with-error-cannot.html

Now that that's in place, the error I'm getting is:

```
(Error) Cannot drop the index 'indexName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I have confirmed that the index does exist, and I'm fairly certain I have permissions to my local instance, which next lead me to think it might be something similar to this: [An explicit DROP INDEX is not allowed even when the constraint is dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696982/an-explicit-drop-index-is-not-allowed-even-when-the-constraint-is-dropped)

**Do any of you know of a solution for faking Schema-bound tables? Is it possible to make this work?  Am I just SOL?**

Thanks.

Comment: Just to verify, the name of the index is 'indexName' ?

Comment: Also, did you remove the schema binding?

Comment: Is the table/index in another schema that is not dbo?  If so you need to add the schema name to the drop statement i.e. DROP INDEX indexname on myschema.<your table>

Comment: @SAS - Nah, the index name is much longer and kind of unimportant to the question.  I may have successfully removed the schemabinding.

Comment: @JM_ I noticed that -- FakeTable doesn't require a SchemaName, but PrepareTableForFaking does, so I now check SchemaName for null, and if it is, I get the name of the schema from the TableName.